# Unknown icon on screen

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

I've noticed an unknown icon on my phone (a new Gionee S6s), next before the `VOLTE2` label, within the top bar, as seen on the screenshot below; it looks like a pined business card.

I am disturbed and would like to know what it is.

Also, how can I possibly get rid of it (if not relevant to me)?

Below is a screenshot of my phone's home screen:
[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Click to enlarge</sup>

Comment: You have several strange things on your screen. To which are you referring?

Comment: Looks like some adwares. Did you install anything recently? Your launcher may be popping this. (Apus Launcher)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Toggle that option off and that icon will leave.